# kendo Treeview datasource binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have main page: main.html

In this page I have a viewmodel with a hierarchical datasource

```
datasource: [{id:"", items:[{.....}]}];
```

In a modal window I have a Treeview. Treeview call a datasource in main page.

In my datasource there is a variable check: true/false

I want that when I check or uncheck a checkbox in the treeview this bind a datasource.. so when I close a modal window, and the I re-open it I will find the selected/unselected checkbox restored...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an HTML like this:

```
<div id="win" class="k-content">
    <div id="treeview"></div>
</div>
```

Where you have a `kendoWindow` which id is `win` containing a `kendoTreeView` with id `treeview`, you should initialize them using:

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    },
    dataSource: data
}).data("kendoTreeView");

var kwin = $("#win").kendoWindow({
    visible  : true,
    modal    : true,
    resizable: false
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

And no matter if the `DataSource` for the `tree` is local (array) or remote. Since you are not going to be destroying the window, just opening and closing, the data is always there.

Running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/q6qpc/)

Comment: why on ie8 the first children the checkchildren work but for other children when i check parentnode che children don't check??

Comment: For example click on: Kendo UI Project
and then click on: Reports

Comment: Which version of kendo ui are you using?

Comment: But i tryed the script on the example that you have created.. and with ie8 that example word how sayd up..

Comment: the example: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/q6qpc/
and try (with ie8) to click on: reports

Comment: You are right, it fails. Check it now in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/q6qpc/1/. This uses the latest release 2012.03.1315 and it works fine (likely a bug already fixed in KendoUI)

Comment: Thank you very much i have resolved the problem is the js i use the trial and i don't have refreshed all files..

Comment: For example i have selected the parent node, and it select all children.
Then i deselect one children, and it deselect the parent node.
But if i see the kendotreeview.dataSource.data() or view() the parent node there is checked but the children is unchecked.. why it don't do the bind of the parent?