# Kendo treeview checkchildren ie

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a treeview

```
   $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: { data: dati.toJSON()
    },
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    },
    selected: false
});
```

But on ie when i check on the Root node the childreb don't checked..
Someone know how to resolve?

The Treeview is in a kendo modal window.

Comment: If this refers to your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560431/kendo-treeview-datasource-binding/14562034#comment20355626_14562034) please read my latest comment, it was a problem in KendoUI fixed on latest release 2012.3.1315

Comment: yes i have result. for other user see the link up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in the latest KendoUI release 2012.03.1315. Now it works fine.